# C language Hangman game, how do i link the scanf with the masked word and have a counter inc for each incorrect input?

Tags: c, random, counter, data-masking

I am making a hangman game, I created a randf to select from a batch of words, aswell as masked the words in order for the guesser to guess the letter of the random word. The issue lies in that I have no idea how to connect the two. I already made the loop but without actually connecting them it will always print when counter = 0 because I have not made the condition for when

`for(int counter; answer != word; counter++;)`

But then I get the error:

> operand types are incompatible, ("char" and "char(*)[200]").

Any solutions?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10

int main()
{
    //randomwordgenerator
    char word[ARRAY_SIZE][200] = { "tiger", "lion", "elephant", "zebra", "horse", "camel", "deer", "crocodile", "rabbit", "cat" };


    int x = 0;
    srand(time(0));

    x = rand() % ARRAY_SIZE;

    system("pause");//will pause the rand function

    //masking and unmasking word
    char m = strlen(word[x]);//will count the number of letters of the random word
    int mask[200]{};
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) //loop until all leters are masked
    {
        mask[i] = 0;
    }

    //Introduction
    printf("Hey! Can you please save me? \n");
    printf(" O\n/|\\ \n/ \\ \n");

    //Ask for answer
    printf("\nType a letter to guess the word and save me. The letter is case sensitive so please pick lower case or I might die\n");
    char answer;
    scanf_s("%d", &answer);

    //loop w counter
    for (int counter = 0; counter++;) {

        if (counter == 0)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
        else if (counter == 1)
        {
            printf("\n=========");
        }
        else if (counter == 2)
        {
            printf("\n+\n|\n|\n|\n|\n|\n=========");
        }
        else if (counter == 3)
        {
            printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|\n|\n|\n|\n=========");
        }
        else if (counter == 4)
        {
            printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|   O\n|\n|\n|\n=========");
        }
        else if (counter == 5)
        {
            printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|   O\n|   |\n|\n|\n=========");
        }
        else if (counter == 6)
        {
            printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|   O\n|   |\n|  / \\ \n|\n=========");
        }
        else if (counter == 7)
        {
            printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|   O\n|  /| \n|  / \\ \n|\n=========");
        }
        else if (counter == 8)
        {
            printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|   O\n|  /|\\ \n|  / \\ \n|\n=========");
        }
        else if (counter == 9)
        {
            printf("\nReally left me hanging there buddy");
            return 0;
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("\nThanks for saving me!");
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: <O/T> `//will pause the rand function` makes no sense,, `rand` has already executed by the time you get to `system("pause");`

Comment: Your for-loop will never run because the initial condition will be false

Comment: for `mask[i] = 0;`, 0 is a string terminator, not a printable char. Hangman typically shows blanks so the player knows how many letters there are and where the revealed letters are vs the hidden ones. You probably want to use `'_'` or `'-'` there.

Comment: `"%c"` is the appropriate `scanf` format specifier to accept a `char` input from the user, not `"%d"` (that's for integers).

Comment: I need the `system("pause")` or I won't get a new rand word when I run the code again. 


I fixed the `mask[i]` to use _ but then how can I show it? I tried printf and it just says argument of type int is incompatible with parameter of type const char

rearrange the scanf to `%c`

Comment: I'm surprised your last `for` loop even compiles given the lack of a conditional check, but even once that gets resolved, the body of your loop is missing the core of hangman. Namely, does the user's guess match a letter(s)? Which one(s)? Where's the check for a win (user guesses all the letters)? Each time thru the loop, you need to 1) accept user's letter choice (bonus points for not allowing a duplicate guess), 2) display the word with guessed and hidden chars, and 3) check if the user has won or ran out of guesses (this is all you're attempting with `counter`).

Comment: I'm dubious. `srand(time(0));` will seed `rand` with a new value each time. If you're getting the same word each time, it's a coincidence, increase your sample size. `system("pause")` has nothing to do with the next invocation of your program anyway. And that should be something like `char mask[200] = { 0 };`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend you to organize your code. Do not hesitate to split it into different functions, and try forcing yourself to respect some kind of style norm (try to declare all your variables at the beginning of your functions for example).

Then try to compile your program regularly and learn to read and understand the errors if you get some. This does not directly answer your question but it can help.

Your `scanf` function stores user input into a variable that you called `answer`. But it seems you don't use your `answer` variable ever again. The solution you proposed (`for(int counter; answer != word; counter++)`) throws an error because you cannot compare two strings with operators in C. You have to use a function like `strcmp()` for this (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html).

Also, do not forget to initialize the `counter` of your `for` loop.

To improve the readability of your code, you can also try to replace your if/else if statements at the end by a switch/case block. [https://www.guru99.com/c-switch-case-statement.html#:~:text=What%20is%20Switch%20Statement%20in,that%20particular%20case%20is%20executed](https://www.guru99.com/c-switch-case-statement.html#:%7E:text=What%20is%20Switch%20Statement%20in,that%20particular%20case%20is%20executed).

Comment: So for the `int counter; answer != word; counter++;` issue all I have to do is add `int strcmp(const char *answer, const char *word);` before the loop, correct? I already have initialized the counter as `int counter = 0;`. I will also look into the switch case method, thank you for the tips

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I did not see you initialized it already.
`int strcmp(const char *answer, const char *word);` is what we call the function prototype, it won't be useful in your situation since `strcmp` should be prototyped and declared in the library you must import to use it.

Comment: There are lots of things to explain but that is the gist of it.

Also, be careful about this line: `for (int counter = 0; counter++;) {`
You put the incrementation of your variable where the loop condition should be.